# Cannot import numpy in python2.7 (macOSX) even though it is installed

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy

So for some reason, I can no longer import the numpy package when I run python in my mac terminal (macOS Sierra). 
I've run pip install numpy and other versions of this and they all tell me that numpy is installed (which I had installed a year ago and had it working fine).

It always says this:

numpy in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages

However, when I run python in my terminal (I even ran it as python2.7) and then type import numpy it says the module is not found...
I actually have no idea how to make it import the module as it constantly tells me that I do have it.

Anyone else face this problem? I really don't know why it won't import anymore (I swear it worked fine a year ago!).

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you have several versions of python installed. The one that is run by default and lives in `/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/` (starts with `/System`) and symlinked to `/usr/bin/python` (`/usr/bin/python2.7`) is called system python (it is better not to touch it). The one that is installed by default in `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/` is usually python3 and is available through `/usr/local/bin/python` (`/usr/local/bin/python3`). If you install something yourself (by downloading from the python.org or through brew install), it will go into `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/` as well and overwrite the symlink `/usr/local/bin/python`.

Since /usr/bin in your PATH is before /usr/local/bin, when you invoke `python`, you invoke the `/usr/bin/python`. That is the simplest solution is to invoke python with the full path /usr/local/bin/python, or make an alias in bash.

But I would recommend using [pyenv](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv) for managing versions of python on your mac. You will not regret, especially if you're going to install [anaconda](https://www.continuum.io/downloads).